Why did the judge eliminate Leslie from the trial?
In the 12th episode of the fourth season of Evil, the judge in charge of Leland Townsend's case, Judge Sebastian

 murders Leslie with some kind of samurai sword that he had hanging in his office, then throws her body into the dumpster below his office.

When Leland asks his demonic lawyer how he managed to prevent Leslie from testifying, the latter only answers vaguely that "every soul has its price."
Why did the judge do this? Was the implication that the judge had been on the side of the Sixty since before the trial? (But why had he even let the trial get to that point, if so?) Was he demonically possessed? Or had he been promised something? (But what could he possibly have been promised to make such a conspicuous murder—the victim disappearing right after he had publicly asked her to meet him in his office, with a weapon that he was known to have there, and all but guaranteed to be discovered in garbage that could be traced back to the courthouse—seem like a good idea?)

Many bodies get thrown in dumpsters. They don't all get traced back to the location they went missing; https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&client=ms-android-google&source=android-browser&q=body+found+at+dump#cobssid=s

@Valorum - He wrapped a body with heavy bleeding in a sheet and threw it into a dumpster in the middle of New York City, in the middle of the day, from an upper story of a crowded courthouse. It's honestly surprising that it was not noticed immediately, never mind  when other people used the dumpster or picked it up. The power of Satan, perhaps.
